# Trouble automatically typing text into textarea

Tags: javascript, textarea, bots

This is a rather long question, as I've tried to include as much detail as I could. If you'd like to skip to the actual question, please see the very last paragraph.

I'm attempting to write a bot to take commands to roll a die like `/r 1d20+2`, evaluating, and sending the response in Javascript within a chat box on the website streamyard.com (as that's what my DM is using to stream D&D).

What I'm having trouble with is "typing" into the textarea field. Here's the HTML of the chat box on the page:

```
<div class="Chat__Wrap-eYhJOs AJLtK">
  <ul class="Chat__Comments-dUewnW eqLtEG">
    <li class="Comment_Wrap-lbwIWt klCgOs">
      <div class="Comment_TextWrap-hSuVQ gHYXCH">
          <p class="Text__StyledText-guhEiE bLDoWl" color="default">test</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <form class="ChatInput__Form-eqBCnG iHgCda">
    <div class="ChatInput__InputWithSmallGutter-fOaQzB dEaxxd Input__Wrap-kXBxwI iUPDqt">
      <label>
        <textarea class="sc-bdVaJa eFZRmf"></textarea>
      </label>
    </div>
    <button class="Button_Wrap-ivpgWU dSirvr ButtonBase__WrapperButton-bsASeg cylsQk" type="submit" color="primary">
      <span class="Button__InnerSpan-iZsIhM jVWFud">Send</span>
    </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

I'm able to get a handle to the text area with the following:

```
var textbox = document.getElementsByClassName("sc-bdVaJa eFZRmf")[1];
```

And I can insert text into it with the following:

```
textbox.value = 'test';
textbox.innerText = 'test';
```

Which causes the textarea to show the value (in this case "test") as being typed in (specifically the `textbox.value` command does this). However, when I go to "send" the message by using the following:

```
var button = document.getElementsByClassName("Button__Wrap-ivpgWU dSirvr ButtonBase__WrapperButton-bsASeg cylsQk");

button[1].click();
```

It doesn't send the chat message that I've "typed" in. It sends nothing at all and doesn't even clear out the textarea as if the button were clicked. Furthermore, if I manually click the button, the same thing happens. Now, if I manually click in the textarea and type anything into it, such as adding a space after the text I programmatically inserted into it, then execute the code above to click the button, it will send the message.

So, this makes me think that there's something it's detecting when the keyboard presses a button that I'm not accounting for by just setting the textarea value. After some Googling, I've found about triggering the `onchange` event. So, I've tried the following:

```
if ("createEvent" in document) {
    var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    evt.initEvent("change", false, true);
    textbox.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
else {
    textbox.fireEvent("onchange");
}
```

However, this simply results in the same as before. I've also tried simulating a key press in the textarea with code like the following:

```
textbox.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress', {'key': 'a'}));
```

However, that also does not seem to work as the "Send" button does not seem to work (and the textarea doesn't seem to populate with the specified key of "a"). But once again, if I were to manually type something into the box, the "Send" button now works as it detected something being entered. I also tried dynamically importing jQuery in and using jQuery to simulate a keypress as seen below:

```
var e1 = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e1.which = 97;
$('textarea.sc-bdVaJa').last().trigger(e1);
var e2 = jQuery.Event("keyup");
e2.which = 97;
$('textarea.sc-bdVaJa').last().trigger(e2);
```

But that simply resulted in the same as above, the 'a' (decimal 97) didn't appear in the textarea, nor did the "Send" button work.

What I thought would be one of the simplest parts of this little project, sending a string of text to a textarea, is turning out to be a lot more difficult than I thought. What I'm looking for is, how do I go about getting a web page to register that new text has been entered into a textarea so that I may "click" a button and have it send the text to a chat?

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't directly solve the issue, this is what I did to get this working. Instead of using the textarea and Send button on the webpage, I decided to cut out the middleman and view the network traffic that's send when a post is made. I then use JavaScript to send a similar request to the server and it successfully posts the message. Here's how I did that.

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("POST", "/api/broadcasts/dug95avkgq/chat", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
xhttp.send('{"text":"<MESSAGE>","name":"<USERNAME>","clientId":"<ID>","color":"#22653f","csrfToken":"<TOKEN>"}');
```